# PRINTDLG OR PAGESETUPDLG

Tags: mfc, windows-ce, winapi

i am trying to launch Printdlg() in my wince device but it is showing me linking error while building . this is the way i am doing it..

```
/// using pagesetupdlg....

PAGESETUPDLG info;
    memset(&info,0,sizeof(info));

    info.lStructSize=sizeof(info);

    PageSetupDlg(&info);
```

or

```
////using printdlg...
PRINTDLG info;
    memset(&info,0,sizeof(info));

    info.lStructSize=sizeof(info);

    PrintDlg(&info);
```

in both case it is showing me ---

> error LNK2019: **unresolved external
>   symbol PageSetupDlgW referenced in
>   function "public: void __cdecl
>   CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedButton1(void)"
>   (?OnBnClickedButton1@CAboutDlg@@QAAXXZ)
>   PrinterTest.obj**

plesae suggest me the solution... 
regards,
mukesh

Answer (score 1):

PageSetupDlg is definitely [supported in the OS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee501755.aspx) so that leaves two questions:

1. Are you linking to commdlg.lib?
2. Is the function included in your OS image/device SDK?

If #1 is true, then it's likely that #2 is false - at least it's not in the SDK.  First, go look at the OS design.  If you don't have access to that, you could try manually pulling it in - I'd try declaring it as an extern first and if that fails, try GetProcAddress.